# Cargar una Url dentro de mi App con Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, url, app, navegador-web

Quisiera saber como Abrir una URL dentro de mi App sin que me salte al navegador externo. quiero hacerlo como me lo hace Intagram Y Facebook. Utilizo Flutter he probado usando la dependencia url_launcher: ^6.0.9 [url_launche dev get](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) pero me salta al navegador quiero hacerlo tal y como Esta en la imagen. alguin que me ayude porfa.

[image: Imagen de lo que quiero hacer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el plugin `webview_flutter` para abrir un navegador embebido.

`https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter`

Agregas la dependencia en `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.12
```

Uso:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

 import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

 class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
 }

 class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
         // Enable hybrid composition.
 if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
     );
   }
 }
```

No te olvides de seguir las instrucciones que indica el plugin.

Comment: Tube que modificar algo En su archivo gradle, simplemente actualice minSdkVersion a 23

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.oaics.customer"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   
}